# Safari accessed pornography at work on accident

Tags: privacy, wifi

My friend sent me a link to porn last night and I clicked on it and laughed.  At work today, I was logged on to their wifi using the password (it automatically connected) I clicked on safari and the porn site tried to load, but instead it said it was blocked by my employer, reason: porn.  I am very worried my employer will think I will try to access porn at work.  I know they would be able to see my iphones IP address but doesn't my cell phone provider keep my name and cell phone number private?

Very worried here.

Thanks

Comment: This is management question, so workplace.SE would be the right place.  I believe this is pretty much the same as what happened here: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/75267/company-policy-violation-due-to-browser-history-syncing

Comment: Start scraping your competitors websites using curl. If they ask tell them you're working on a competitive intelligence project to make your company more profitable. Maybe it accidentally followed a bad link...

Comment: My question is more around my cell phone provider.  I know that my work will see my IP address, but will they see my name and/or cell phone number? Doesn't my cell phone provider have privacy to me?

Comment: If you accessed the link through your cell phone connected to the mobile network then your office network didn't even see the request. Otherwise your office network has your device's MAC address, possibly the credentials used to sign into the network if WPA Enterprise is used.

Comment: It was through the company wifi.  I don't care if they have my IP address I'm more concerned about my name being revealed for a simple mistake. :(

Comment: In any case, what's the big deal? There *is* porn on the internet, and accidently stumbling on it through a link on a social network is totally plausible. If anyone asks, tell them the truth that someone sent you the link yesterday and it remained open in your browser, and move on.

Comment: Was it really funny porn?

Answer (score 9):

I used to be one of the guys who ran the tool that filters web content (WebSense) at an organization and you gotta believe me, the tens of thousands of blocked requests to forbidden sites I saw all day every day did not register with anyone unless there was a discernible pattern.  If you made a habit of it, it might generate an alert and if there were enough alerts someone might investigate what the hell you were up to.

And that is for company owned computers where we knew who had what IP address.  As far as IP address of employee owned devices, the idea that they will spend precious time figuring out whose phone it is is... well, laughable.  Your one mistake is buried by the guy who went to a malware site that attempted to connect to 100 blocked sites in the span of 60 seconds.  And by the flood of phishing emails that generated another 1000 attempted visits to blocked sites, and so on.   or by data requests from HR to respond to complaints about such-and-such and employee... or by requests from management to open up dropbox.  Trust me, that one blocked request is buried in an avalanche of data.

The first day I got that job, I thought I would be tempted to figure out who was going to "bad" sites.  Nope.  Not only did I not have time to investigate anything besides "oh my God, we're being attacked" traffic, it became instantly boring, the way a doctor gets bored with the human body, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine.

From my standpoint someone might look into it, but nobody likely will.  If someone does look into it, chances are that they will only be able to get your phones IP address at that time and your phone's MAC address.

If someone really wanted to, they could come track you down next time you connect to the wifi, but that is more work than I would have considered worth it.